# Reading and Writing Data Excel File Classic ASP

Tags: sql, excel, asp-classic, excel-2007

I want to be able to read from and write to an excel file using Classic ASP stored in my local machine at

```
C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\excel\excel.xls
```

I tried using the following code:

```
<% 
' Set Connection Params 
Set oConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.connection") 
oConn.Open "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)}; DriverId=790;" &_ 
"DBQ=c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\excel\excel.xls;" &_ 
"DefaultDir = C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\excel\" 

Set RS=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset") 

' Write the SQL Query 
RS.open "SELECT * FROM my_range", oConn 

do until RS.EOF 
Response.Write ( RS("NAME") & " -- " & RS("EMAIL") & "") 
RS.movenext 
Loop 

'Close the recordset/connection 

RS.Close 
oConn.Close 
Set RS = Nothing 
%>
```

Which I got from [here](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial143_Extract-data-from-Excel-Spreadsheet-using-ASP.html)

But I got the following error:

```
    Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005'

[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

/ASP/excel.asp, line 4
```

I'm just a beginner with ASP and not sure what to do. Please help out!

Answer (score 1):

1. Is your server a 64 bit machine.  If it is you may need to enable 32 bit applications in your application pool
2. You could try one of the connection strings here. http://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-jet-ole-db-4-0/

If you have a copy of MS Access I recommend that you import your excel spreadsheet into an Access database and connect to that.  Using excel directly as a datasource can be painful.